# ArcGIS JavaScript manually render a layer with supplied JSON

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, json, rendering

Given the following JSON which is retrieved outside the ArcGIS/dojo framework, how would I go about rendering this layer?

```
    {
        "currentVersion": 10.01,
        "serviceDescription": "",
        "mapName": "Layers",
        "description": "",
        "copyrightText": "",
        "layers": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Transportation Stations-unexpired",
                "parentLayerId": -1,
                "defaultVisibility": true,
                "subLayerIds": null,
                "minScale": 400000,
                "maxScale": 0
            }
        ],
        "tables": [],
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 102100
        },
        "singleFusedMapCache": false,
        "initialExtent": {
            "xmin": -10398329.13791846,
            "ymin": 2687052.938617364,
            "xmax": -7541451.81403804,
            "ymax": 5379667.868452799,
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 102100
            }
        },
        "fullExtent": {
            "xmin": -10152568.449939176,
            "ymin": 2795685.894150028,
            "xmax": -7787215.334097848,
            "ymax": 5828927.975739868,
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 102100
            }
        },
        "units": "esriMeters",
        "supportedImageFormatTypes": "PNG24,PNG,JPG,DIB,TIFF,EMF,PS,PDF,GIF,SVG,SVGZ,AI,BMP",
        "documentInfo": {
            "Title": "test.mxd",
            "Author": "test",
            "Comments": "",
            "Subject": "",
            "Category": "",
            "Keywords": "",
            "Credits": ""
        },
        "capabilities": "Map,Query,Data"
    }
```

Comment: This is just the Mpaservice's information in JSON. It does not contain any data, or urls from where the ESRI JSAPI could request the map images.